# Google Maps API v3 is not showing marker

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm trying to place a marker on a google map, but it doesn't show up. The map shows fine and with the center at the right location, but then I use that location for the marker - and it does nothing. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Code is as follows:

```
  if (maps.geocoder) {
    maps.geocoder.geocode(
        { 'address' : mapInfo.address },
        function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                mapInfo.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        map : mapInfo.map,
                        posision : results[0].geometry.location,
                    }
                )

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<b><u><a href='" + mapInfo.url + "'>" + mapInfo.title + "</a></u></b><br>" + mapInfo.address
                });

                infowindow.open(mapInfo.map,marker);

                marker.setVisible(true)
                console.log(marker)
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Google Maps: Адрес не найден по следующей причине: " + status);
            }
        }
    )
  }
```

Comment: unbelievable! thank you so much! :D